# how to check if SharePoint content databases are corrupt?

Tags: sql-server, database-server

I have SharePoint 2010 and would like to check if the databases are corrupt or not.

Can someone tell me how can I do that either via powershell or T-SQL without making any modifications to the databases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`DBCC CheckDb` is the appropriate way to check for corruption in any SQL database. There are a few options as to what to check. Evaluate what the correct options are in your scenario.

[DBCC CHECKDB (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your reply. Could you please tell me how can I check that using powershell as the administrator will not give me access to SQL Server.

Comment: Nothing you can do from the SharePoint side. This must be accomplished via T-SQL.